# Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>' ANGULAR 6

Tags: javascript, angular

Eu criei um interceptor para pegar todos os erros usando o angular 6, porem o catch retorna essa mensagem.

```
 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
    return next.handle(req)
        .catch((error, caught) => {

         (....)

           return Observable.throw(errorObj);
        }) as any;
  };
}
```

Eu pesquisei bastante e encontrei que no angular 6 deveria ser usado o:

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError,  Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Porem nem assim as coisas funcionam por aqui.
Eu tentei tambem o:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Mas o angular diz: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/catch' in '...'

Comment: Leia o [Guia de atualização da RxJS 5.x para v6 (em Inglês)](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#rxjs-v5x-to-v6-update-guide)

Comment: comenta ali q marco como resolvido.

Comment: não, botei a solução abaixo. Teve uma mudança no rxjs pra adicionar o .pipe. Mas o manual q m mandaste m ajudou a encontrar essa solução.

Answer (score 1):

resolvi alterando o código e deixando dessa maneira:

```
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
    return next.handle(req)
        .pipe(
        catchError((error, caught) => {
          (...)
        }
     return observableThrowError(errorObj);
        })) as any;
```

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#deprecations

Comment: noob, não consigo marcar seu comentario como resolvido. Acho q s vc responder eu conseguirei.

Comment: Você já respondeu com a solução, seria interessante se poder explicar como resolveu o problema, caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema futuramente.